# Show that the triangle $ABC$ is right-angled in $C$.

Tags: geometry

**Question**

Show that the triangle $ABC$ is right-angled in $C$ if and only if the relation is true (the notations are the usual ones) $\frac{c - b}{p - b} + \frac{c - a}{p - a } = \frac{a+b}{p}$ , where $a \neq c \neq b$

**My idea**

I replaced $p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ and i got that and divided by 2 and got $\frac{c-b}{a+c-b}+\frac{c-a}{c+b-a}=\frac{a+b}{a+b+c}$

From here we have 2 cases:

1. We know that the triangle is right-angled. We show the relation.
2. We know the relation. We show that the triangle is right-angled.

I was able to show the first case and here is how I demonstrate it:

We apply the Pytaghora Theorem and we get  that $a^2+b^=c^2$ which will make $a^2=c^2-b^2=(c+b)(c-b)=> (c-b)=\frac{a^2}{c+b}$

$\frac{c-b}{a+c-b}=\frac{a^2}{a(c+b)+a^2}=\frac{a}{a+b+c}$

Similarry we get that $\frac{c-a}{c+b-a}=\frac{b}{a+b+c}$

Adding the two equality up we get the relation wanted.

I don't know how to demonstrate the second case.

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Try and rewrite your first proof as $(a^2 + b^2 - c^2 ) \times P = 0, P \neq 0$. Then the result follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has algebraically showed that
$$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \Rightarrow \frac{ c-b}{a+c-b } + \frac{ c-a} { c+b - a }  = \frac{ a + b } { a+b+c}.$$

With that information, for such if and only if statements, what that often (but not always) implies is that

$$ \frac{ c-b}{a+c-b } + \frac{ c-a} { c+b - a }  - \frac{ a + b } { a+b+c} =  (a^2+b^2 - c^2 ) \times P(a, b, c).$$

Then, to prove iff, we merely need to show that $P(a, b, c) \neq 0$ under the conditions of the problem.

---

In this particular case, we do indeed get

> $$ \frac{ c-b}{a+c-b } + \frac{ c-a} { c+b - a }  - \frac{ a + b } { a+b+c} \\ = (a^2+b^2 - c^2 ) \times \frac{-2c}{(a+c-b)(c+b-a)(a+b+c) }. $$

Under the conditions that $a, b, c$ are side lengths of a triangle, we do have $P(a, b, c) \neq 0 $ and is well defined. So

$$ \frac{ c-b}{a+c-b } + \frac{ c-a} { c+b - a }  - \frac{ a + b } { a+b+c} = 0  \Leftrightarrow  (a^2+b^2 - c^2 ) = 0$$

---

Note: Using what OP has shown,

$$ \frac{c-b}{a+c-b} - \frac{a}{a+b+c} = (a^2+b^2-c^2) \times \frac{1}{(a-b+c)(a+b+c) } $$

$$ \frac{c-a}{b+c-a} - \frac{b}{a+b+c} = (a^2+b^2-c^2) \times \frac{1}{(b-a+c)(a+b+c) } $$

In that sense, they have done all of the hard work.